# Delegate method not calling

Tags: objective-c, delegates, push

Apple push notification alert, sound and badge received on iPhone. But not calling:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
```

This method not calling. What can I do?

Comment: show some more info of your app

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use the delegate callback for remote notifications not local notifications

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```